# Difficult Integrand

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to integrating the following function. I am getting nowhere.

$$2^{-n} n \int_0^1 w \log ^2(w) \left(2 w+w \log ^2(w)-2 w \log (w)\right)^{n-1} dw$$,

Any Suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

The domain is (0, 1)

Comment: I have edited your post so that it is easier to read. Please verify that my edit is correct.

Comment: Start by substituting for $\log w$

Comment: Might help to notice that the domain for w is all real numbers greater than 0. Also w cannot equal 1.

Comment: Why can't $w$ equal one?

Comment: I think w can equal 1

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=-\log w$ to obtain

$$2^{-n} n \int_0^\infty e^{-3t} t^2 (t^2-2t+2)^{n-1} dt.
$$

Then use a multinomial expansion and the properties of the exponential distribution and you're done.

Comment: I don't understand how the limits of integration changed from (0,1) to (0,$\infty$).

Comment: @PierreMFiorini Using the substitution formula $t=-\log{w}$, $w=0$ becomes $t=-\log{0}=+\infty$, and $w=1$ becomes $t=-\log{1}=0$.

Comment: No, the answer above is not correct. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, it's not correct because the question keeps getting changed.